# CocoaAMF in ipad development

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

In my project right now data between client and server is exchanged in AMF format. We want to migrate this project on iOS flatform. Hence we are planning to develop an ipad app.

I found CocoaAMF library, however I am not aware any other apps using this library. Also, does anyone know if apps which are using these library has been accepted by apple store.

Are there any other resources that can be used if I have to use AMF format to exchange data?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

That library is the best choice for AMF on iOS.

Comment: hi, i try to add the AMFClient with my app... but it creates error and i completed simple call to remoteserver and return proper object. but not with AMF Client plz give some proper docs.. so i can integrate it properly.